# What is the difference between a constructor and a builder when using generics?

Tags: java, generics, lombok

While programming in Java, I encountered the following problem.

when use Constructor: The following code works fine.

```java
public class Generics<T> {

    private T data;

    public static <T> Generics<T> of(T data) {
        return new Generics<>(data);
    }

    public Generics(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

when use builder: An error occurs saying that the Object type is provided as follows.

[image]

I used a builder provided by Project Lombok.

Why doesn't the builder generic in the code above work?

Comment: I used lombok. You can see @Builder in the photo above.

Comment: @paiwmsn Are you asking when each pattern is best employed or simply how to implement the builder pattern with lombok?

Comment: You are using `Generics.builder()`, but haven't provided a type argument to the builder, hence it's a *raw type*.

Comment: How about `Generics<T>.builder()`?

Comment: More likely to be `Generics.<T>builder()` if `builder()` is a generic static method. I don't know what exactly lombok generates.

Comment: `Generics.<T>builder()` is working. very thank you!!!

Comment: The differences between a constructor and a builder should be no different if you use Lombok or something else. In general, a constructor is a special method that has no return type and its name is the same as the class object it needs to construct. A builder is a pattern used for the same purpose as the constructor. The pattern (mostly) uses a inner class that returns an instance of the outer class. A builder allows you to build an object in stages, whereas the constructor only allows the construction of a class object in one shot. For that reason, builders should be preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evidently Lombok generates a static generic `builder()` method. You can specify the generic type of a generic static method using `<T>` before the method name, as in:

```
return Generics.<T>builder()
          .data(data)
          .build();
```

If you don't specify the generic type when you call `builder()`, you get a raw type, at which point generic type inference no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly add the generics: `return Generics.<T>builder()` - add that `<T>` and all will be well.

### Explanation

Java is aggressively typed: Every expression and just about every part of an expression has an actual type; java does not allow things to remain in limbo until later; there's no such thing as 'an intermediate - eh, we'll see where it goes'.

That means `Generics.builder()`, as an expression, needs to be typed by the system. The builder class needs that `<T>` just the same (it's a `Generics.GenericsBuilder<X>` - where `Builder` is a static inner class of Generics, and is defined as `public static class GenericsBuilder<X>`.

Java cannot just jump to the conclusion that you intend for X and T to be the same type.

Looking ahead, it can figure out that X should be T 'automatically', without your involvement: It can either check the `.data(data)` invocation, given that the `data` method is defined in the builder as:

```
public GenericsBuilder<X> data(X data)
```

thus, whatever type `data` (the variable)`might  be (it's`T`here, given that it's the parameter defined as`T data`), and therefore, java can conclude that the X should be T.

Otherwise, java can look even further ahead, to `build()`, and notice that this returns `X`, and is being returned by a method whose return type is defined as `T`, thus also giving java the opportunity to say: Ah, X == T, right.

**But that is not how java works**. In large part because even figuring out what the `.data` method might mean is rather hard to do when the `X` of that builder you just made (the `X` in the declaration `public static <X> Generics.GenericsBuilder<X> builder()`) must be left in some sort of unknown limbo state for a while as the parser carries on with trying to figure out what the rest means. Given that java allows method overloading (2 different methods with the same name and the same number of params, but different param types, which could contain generics to boot) - it'd be a combinatorial explosion and means you can write java code that takes literally years to parse.

Hence, java does not work that way, it must determine what `X` is supposed to be *solely* from the expression `Generics.builder()`, and it clearly cant.

The solution is to just write it explicitly, using this somewhat exotic syntax: `Generics.<T>builder()`.